# Is it posible to find index-row and values with QRegExp with search name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qregexp, qsortfilterproxymodel

I want to find the row-index with searching word using with `QSortFilterProxyModel` and `QtCore.QRegExp`.
I want to create a list with  "mobile" and "email" columns only from the row which is finding from the variable of `QRegExp`.
Below is example code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtSql
    
    
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("users.db")
    
if db.open():
    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query.exec_("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_name(name TEXT, age TEXT, mobile TEXT, mail TEXT)""")
    
model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable("table")
model.select()
    
proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
proxy.setSourceModel(model)
    
query.exec_("INSERT into users VALUES ('name1', 29, 123, 'Mail1.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into users VALUES ('name2', 30, 456, 'Mail2.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into users VALUES ('name3', 31, 789, 'Mail3.com')")
    
search_name = "name2"
    
search = QtCore.QRegExp(search_name)
proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)
list_a = []
```

I want to print the `row.index` and insert the value of "mobile" and "email" of the row into `list_a`.
How is it possible or is there any other solution for Request?

Comment: 1) Please avoid creating several posts with the same question, 2) Use the main tags since the secondary tags are not followed by many members of the community so few (almost nobody) can help you.

Comment: I got the point that importance of the main Tags. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a model to filter elements based on a regex since the Qt sqlite driver allows to use the `regex` function enabling it through `QSQLITE_ENABLE_REGEXP` using `setConnectOptions()` method:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtSql

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("users.db")
db.setConnectOptions("QSQLITE_ENABLE_REGEXP=1")

if not db.open():
    sys.exit(-1)

query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query.exec_(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_name(name TEXT, age TEXT, mobile TEXT, mail TEXT)"""
)

query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name1', 29, 123, 'Mail1.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name2', 30, 456, 'Mail2.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name3', 31, 789, 'Mail3.com')")

query_filter = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query_filter.prepare("SELECT rowid, * FROM user_name WHERE regexp(?, name) ")
query_filter.addBindValue("name1")

if query_filter.exec_():
    record = query_filter.record()
    while query_filter.next():
        print("=======")
        for i in range(record.count()):
            print(record.fieldName(i), query_filter.value(i))
else:
    print(query_filter.lastError().text())
```

If you still want to use QSqlTableModel then you can also use the setFilter method:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtSql

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("users.db")
db.setConnectOptions("QSQLITE_ENABLE_REGEXP=1")

if not db.open():
    sys.exit(-1)

query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query.exec_(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_name(name TEXT, age TEXT, mobile TEXT, mail TEXT)"""
)

model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable("user_name")
model.select()

query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name1', 29, 123, 'Mail1.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name2', 30, 456, 'Mail2.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name3', 31, 789, 'Mail3.com')")

model.setFilter("regexp('%s', name)" % ("name1"))

model.select()
for i in range(model.rowCount()):
    r = model.record(i)
    print("=====")
    for j in range(r.count()):
        print(r.fieldName(j), r.value(j))
```

If you still want to use QSqlTableModel + QSQSortFilterProxyModel then apart from the filter you have to map the position of the rows:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtSql

db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("users.db")

if not db.open():
    sys.exit(-1)

query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
query.exec_(
    """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_name(name TEXT, age TEXT, mobile TEXT, mail TEXT)"""
)

model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel()
model.setTable("user_name")
model.select()

proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
proxy.setSourceModel(model)

query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name1', 29, 123, 'Mail1.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name2', 30, 456, 'Mail2.com')")
query.exec_("INSERT into user_name VALUES ('name3', 31, 789, 'Mail3.com')")

model.select()

search_name = "name2"

search = QtCore.QRegExp(search_name)
proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)

for i in range(proxy.rowCount()):
    r = model.record()
    print("=====")
    print("row", proxy.mapToSource(proxy.index(i, 0)).row())
    for j in range(r.count()):
        index = proxy.index(i, j)
        print(r.fieldName(j), index.data())
```